Cannot boot into Ubuntu after CPU replacement
I replaced my CPU, going from Intel 12600K to 13900, but I'm now longer able to boot into Ubuntu (24). It's going into GNU Grub, and when I select Ubuntu / recovery mode, the screen goes black for a while and then the computer reboots.

In grub, I found /boot/grub in (hd0,gpt2) and ran the following:
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
set prefix=(hd0,gpt2)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal

However this took me to the Grub menu again, and when I hit enter on Ubuntu, the screen went black for like 5 minutes, at which point I turned off the computer.
After this, I tried to boot from a USB stick. My other machine is a Mac, so I followed these steps found here:
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
When I tried to boot from from the USB, I got the follow error for both Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and 24.04 LTS
error file '/boot/' not found

Note that I've used this exact USB and followed the exact procedure outlined in the link above to install Ubuntu a few months earlier without any issues. The only difference is that I've upgraded the motherboard bios since then.
In grub, I can see that after plugging in my USB, (hd1,gpt2)/ contains directories, like /home, /etc, /usr, /tmp, /snap as well as /boot/grub/
Additional Information
After installing the new CPU, my RAM was situated incorrectly and gave no signal to the monitor incorrectly, and I had to start and stop the computer several times before finding the issue. I'm not sure if this would have corrupted the bootloader.
Motherboard used: Asrock Z690 mITX/ax


Welcome to AskUbuntu. This sort of issue is often the result of something in the UEFI rather than the OS itself. Some motherboards need to be factory reset after a CPU upgrade. Some need to be checked to see if Secure Boot was re-enabled. Others need to have C-States setting changed to disabled. I do not have any motherboards from Asrock handy, so cannot offer specific things to check.

Do you have latest firmware from Asrock for UEFI? And if SSD, latest firmware for it? Ubuntu released new ISO for current systems because Microsoft August update broke UEFI Secure boot for LInux systems. Make sure you have newest ISO, which has the fixes required.
